# Custom ListAdapter NOT displaying all fields

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a class with several fields, only one of them I want displayed in the ListView

```
class FOO {
   String f1;
   String f2;
   String f3;
};
FOO foo = new FOO;
FOO [] fooArray = new FOO[5];
```

I was using a standard ArrayAdapter to display this and was adding foo.f1 as the field to display in the ListView. I can of course sort on foo.f1. I now need to be able to sort on foo.f2 or foo.f3. I could build a custom ArrayAdapter that would take foo as its element, but only display foo.f1. And then I would have access to foo.f2 and foo.f3 and could sort on those fields. Is there a simpler way of doing this, without having to create a custom ArrayAdapter?

The array of foo elements is available outside of the ArrayAdapter, I could sort it, delete all the elements from the ArrayAdapter and then re-add them in the new sorted way, but I'd like to use the sort function of the ArrayAdapter.

Any pointers are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ArrayAdapter.sort`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29) takes a `Comparator` object as a parameter. So you might have three differentcomparators or a parametrized comparator and sort items as you wish.

```
Comparator<FOO> f1 = new Comparator<FOO>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(FOO lhs, FOO rhs) {          
        return lhs.f1.compareTo(rhs.f1);
    }
};

Comparator<FOO> f2 = new Comparator<FOO>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(FOO lhs, FOO rhs) {          
        return lhs.f2.compareTo(rhs.f2);
    }
};
```

...
    myListAdapter.sort(f1);
    myListAdapter.sort(f2);

Comment: This would work, if the ArrayAdapter was an array of FOO types, but it's an array of Strings, added to the adapter via a loop myListAdapter.add(fooArray[i].f1). If I were to make the ArrayAdapter an array of FOO types, but only want to display FOO.f1, then don't I have to build a custom ArrayAdapter so that it would know how to display its items? I only want to display FOO.f1, regardless of which field I am using for sorting.

Comment: Why don't make an array adapter of FOO then? You might subclass ArrayAdapter, override getView and make it show only f1 field.

ArrayAdapter<FOO> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FOO>(){ ...

Or you might leave ArrayAdapter as it is and override FOO's toString to return f1 value

Comment: Overriding FOO's toString is the easiest way to go, thank you for your suggestion.